# replace/remove everything before a specified string

Tags: pandas, replace

I have a string in a pandas dataframe.

`This is target 1`

`We also have target 2`

I want to remove all text before the `target` string so it turns into:

`target 1`

`target 2`

I've been looking through regex patterns, but I'm struggling to find a solution. I've looked at lstrip() but that's for white space. It wont always be two words to be removed so I can't split by spaces and use a tail select [-2].

This is as far as I have got so far, but I'm at a loss of the best way to replace everything before `target` and retain `target`.

`df['point_id'].str.replace()`

Comment: target is always at end or it may be in any position?

Comment: target could be anywhere, more could be after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove everything before the first `target`, you can use `^.*?(?=target)`, where:

1. `^` matches the beginning of string;
2. `.*?` matches everything non-greedily;
3. `?=target` asserts that the match is before pattern `target`;

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['This is target 1', 'we also have target 2', 'With target 2 and target 3']})

df.col.str.replace('^.*?(?=target)', '')    

0                 target 1
1                 target 2
2    target 2 and target 3
Name: col, dtype: object
```